# checkbox values not being received in laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, checkbox, controller, laravel-blade

I have this bit of code in my form `edit.blade.php` :

```
@php
    $imagepath="images/Service/".$services->name."/";
    $images=glob($imagepath.'*.*');   
@endphp

<div class="row">
     @foreach($images as $image)
         @php
             $count++;
         @endphp

         <div class="col-md-5">
             <img src="{{URL::asset($image)}}"  style="height: 150px;object-fit: contain;">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-1">
             <input form="services" type="checkbox"  name="deleteimagelink[]" value="{{($image)}}"  >
         </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

This is for passing the path of those images meant to be deleted.
And I have this snippet in my controller:

```
print_r($request->input('deleteimagelink'));
$deletables=$request->input('deleteimagelink');
foreach ($deletables as $deletable)
{
    print_r($deletable);
    unlink($deletable);    
}
```

I have this problem that nothing is being received in the `$request->input('deleteimagelink')` parameter. 
Please guide me if I'm doing anything wrong.
If nothing seems weird, can you please guide me how to deal with these checkbox situations in laravel.
I consulted related answers from internet but nothing seems to work.

Comment: How are you submitting these inputs to the server? ajax? standard form? and (I know this is a stupid question - but gotta ask to be sure...) are any of the checkboxes actually 'checked'?

Comment: I'm using regular forms for submission. And yes, Ive checked varying number of checkboxes to check for it and the results are all same.

Comment: There are other elements in the form too, including new file uploads. All are well received in the controller but just this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had included the code above outside the `<form></form>` tag in order to justify to my view. Interestingly, it didn't work even though that I had included `form="services"` as a parameter in my input field{services is the form name here}. I had worked something like this before and it had worked pretty good that time. I managed to get the `<form></form>` tags outside the whole of my form elements and it is working fine now.
Thank you everybody who tried to help.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form class="form-group" method="post" action="/destroy" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     @csrf
    <input type="checkbox"  name="deleteimagelink[]" value="1"  >
      <input type="checkbox"  name="deleteimagelink[]" value="2"  >
     <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Actualizar</button
      </form>
```

Controller

`public function destroy(Request $request)
    {
        return $request;
    }`

> {"_token":"BetJnyujXvJnpkkwDU31kYO7lVz5OqflMQDoCLQy","deleteimagelink":["1","2"]}

This Works for me!

Comment: Im sending an array of deleteimagelink. The field is inside the foreach loop. So, it requires this [ ] Jose

Comment: Thank you Jose. But I figured out how I could get it right. {Still didn't get what wrong I was doing though.} ;) Cheers.